# Changing colors of drupal tables

Tags: theming

I noticed that drupal always use grey as background and line color with tables.

I prefer to avoir modifying the code of my template. Is there any way to modify the ugly grey drupal tables ?

Comment: write your own css style colors

Comment: Thanks but where do I put the css style (I don't want to modify the template) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it. Here are two of them:

**Through your theme**

- write your own mainstyle.css file.
- place it in your active theme directory (directly or in a folder that you create there)
- go to that theme directory and open the file: [themename].info (e.g. bartik.info or myAwesomeTheme.info)
- add `stylesheets[all][] = mainstyle.css` after the existing stylesheets. (or `stylesheets[all][] = css/mainstyle.css` if your stylesheet is placed in a folder called 'css').
- flush your cache

This way drupal will include your stylesheet.

**A simpler way to do it** , with the help of a **module**, so that you don't touch any of your files, is

- download the module  [css injector](https://drupal.org/project/css_injector)
- enable the module
- go to configuration -> development -> css injector (admin/config/development/css-injector)
- create a new rule and give a name to the rule: e.g. table styling
- Finally in this rule write your CSS  e.g. `td {background-color: red;}` etc

Tip: If you want to target your elements (e.g. tables) correctly, then you may need firebug, which is an extension for Firefox.